# C# & SQL Server : Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to get data from the SQL Server database but the error state that

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

This is my table

[TourDisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl4jg.jpg)

My code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=....;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader dtr;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();

    cmd.CommandText = "select BicycleType from TourDisplay order by TDateTime asc";

    dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    bool temp = false;

    while (dtr.Read())
    {
        TBBicycleType.Text = dtr.GetString(0);
        TBBicycleType2.Text = dtr.GetString(1);
        temp = true;
    }     
}
```

As you can see, the code should be fine because I got 3 data inside the table but I'm having problem on `GetString(1)`.

Comment: Could you please include more code, I mean the query and how you are populating the `dtr`. Then it would be easy for us to find the issue

Comment: I think you should use dtr[0], dtr[1]..

Comment: @un-lucky please check my edited post.

Comment: it looks like you are only selecting one column: `BicycleType` but trying to fetch two from the read array.  Either select more columns in your sql statement, or remove the second GetString

Comment: See,  in the query you are selecting one column ie, `BicycleType` and you are trying to access the second column using `GetString()` which is not yet fetched. Your issue will be fixed if you add the second column name in the query

Comment: @WhiteRuski But I want to retrieve data only in the column BicycleType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that in your select statement, you are selecting ONE column, but in the reader, you're trying to select two.

EXAMPLE: `SELECT Id, BicycleType FROM TourDisplay ORDER BY TDateTime`

Please either add another column to your select statement, or remove the second selector from the reader:

`TBBicycleType2.Text = dtr.GetString(1);`

**Edit per comment**

It appears that you may be trying to set two different buttons, using the first two results from your query with this while reader loop.  I'd tweak it a little as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT BicycleType FROM TourDisplay ORDER BY TDateTime";
    dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    bool temp = false;

    // Added this variable.  name it anything you like.
    bool isFirstItem = true;
    while (dtr.Read())
    {
        // After the first loop iteration, isFirstItem will be set to false
        if (isFirstItem)
        {
            TBBicycleType.Text = dtr.GetString(0);
            isFirstItem = false;
        }
        // All consequent iterations of the loop will set the second 
        // item's 'Text' property.  So if you have only two rows, it 
        // will be the second row.  If you have 20 rows, it will be the 20th row.
        else
            TBBicycleType2.Text = dtr.GetString(0);

        temp = true;
    }     
}
```

**Although, if you're just setting two buttons using a while loop and from the database, I'd rethink your design a little?**

**Edit 2** per changes to the OP mentioning 3 total rows in the database

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT BicycleType FROM TourDisplay ORDER BY TDateTime";
    dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // Again, I'd rethink your design, but if you're just playing
    // around this should be fine
    int count = 0;
    while (dtr.Read())
    {
        switch (count)
        {
            case 0:
                TBBicycleType.Text = dtr.GetString(0);
                break;
            case 1:
                TBBicycleType2.Text = dtr.GetString(0);
                break;
            // Add whatever you want to do with the third one here
            // case 2:
            //     TBBicycleType3.Text = dtr.GetString(0);
            //     break;
         }
        count++;
    }     
}
```

Comment: I see my mistake now, but I'm trying to get data only from column BicycleType to be put inside the texbox.

Comment: I'm not using any button, but I want to retrieve the data once the page is loaded.

Comment: @nao the variable name doesn't matter. you can name it anything.  if you refresh you can see i changed it to `isFirstTextbox`.  Please just try it and let me know if it works.  You can name it `isItAKittyCat` or whatever else you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It still not 100% for what I want, but I get the idea now.

Answer (score 1):

The index is indeed out of bounds. Since you're trying to get the second column on dtr.getString(1). To fix, remove the dtr.getString(1).

In each iteration, dtr.GetString(0) gets the next row of BicycleType. So first iteration,  TBBicycleType.Text = "Time Trial". Second iteration, TBBicycleType.Text = "MTB". and so on.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=....;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader dtr;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select BicycleType from TourDisplay order by TDateTime asc";
    dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    bool temp = false;
    while (dtr.Read())
    {
        TBBicycleType.Text = dtr.GetString(0);
        temp = true;
    }     
}
```